# Installing let's encrypt on Amazon Linux2023

Tags: nginx, ssl-certificate, lets-encrypt, certbot, amazon-linux

I am trying to get SSL certificate with let's encrypt nginx. First, I added epel using the commands `$ wget https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm` and `$ sudo rpm -ihv --nodeps ./epel-release-latest-8.noarch.rpm` and it installed with no problem then I tried `sudo yum install python3-certbot-nginx` and got the error message:

```
Problem: package certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch requires python3-certbot = 1.22.0-1.el8, 
but none of the providers can be installed
  - conflicting requests
  - nothing provides python3.6dist(setuptools) >= 39.0.1 needed by python3-certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides python3.6dist(cryptography) >= 2.5.0 needed by python3-certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides python3.6dist(configobj) >= 5.0.6 needed by python3-certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides python3.6dist(distro) >= 1.0.1 needed by python3-certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides /usr/bin/python3.6 needed by python3-certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides python3.6dist(pytz) needed by python3-certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch
  - nothing provides python(abi) = 3.6 needed by python3-certbot-1.22.0-1.el8.noarch
  (try to add '--skip-broken' to skip uninstallable packages)
```

I also tried `sudo dnf install python3-certbot-nginx` but got a similar error.
I learned i may need a Code ready builder but haven't been able to install it. Please how can I get it. If that is not the issue, please what I'm I doing wrong and how can I resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this exact same problem so I tried using the epel-release-**9** package. This solved it for me:

sudo dnf install https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/epel-release-latest-9.noarch.rpm

Answer (score 0):

#ssl_cert https://certbot.eff.org/instructions?ws=nginx&os=pip

sudo dnf install python3 augeas-libs

sudo python3 -m venv /opt/certbot/

sudo /opt/certbot/bin/pip install --upgrade pip

sudo /opt/certbot/bin/pip install certbot certbot-nginx

sudo ln -s /opt/certbot/bin/certbot /usr/bin/certbot

sudo certbot --nginx

echo "0 0,12 * * * root /opt/certbot/bin/python -c 'import random; import time; time.sleep(random.random() * 3600)' && sudo certbot renew -q" | sudo tee -a /etc/crontab > /dev/null

sudo /opt/certbot/bin/pip install --upgrade certbot certbot-nginx